# Rewriting lodash 'fill' function

Tags: javascript, lodash

I rewrited the [fill](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#fill) function of lodash for the purpose of training JS.
Please, rewrite it better than me.

```
//////////////// fill(array, value, [start=0], [end=array.length]) ////////////////
```

Fills elements of array with value from start up to, but not including, end.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];

function fill (arr, filler, start = 0, end = arguments[0].length) { 
  filler = new Array(end - start).fill(filler);
  let temp = arr;
  temp.splice(start,end === arguments[0].length ? end : end - 1, ...filler);
  return temp
}

console.log(fill(array, 'a')); 
// => ['a', 'a', 'a']

console.log(fill(Array(3), 2));
// => [2, 2, 2]

console.log(fill([4, 6, 8, 10], '*', 1, 3));
// => [4, '*', '*', 10]

console.log(fill([4, 6, 8, 10,12,14,18,20], '*', 1, 3));
// => [4, "*", "*", 10, 12, 14, 18, 20]
```

Is there a more elegant way to approach this?

Comment: You're looking for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use a simple for loop? `for(let i = start; i < end; i++) arr[i] = filler`

Answer (score 1):

The [`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method is almost identical to lodash's [`_.fill()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#fill). The main difference is the way that it is applied to the array.

```js
const fill = (arr, ...args) => arr.fill(...args);

console.log(fill([1, 2, 3], 'a')); // => ['a', 'a', 'a']

console.log(fill(Array(3), 2)); // => [2, 2, 2]

console.log(fill([4, 6, 8, 10], '*', 1, 3)); // => [4, '*', '*', 10]

console.log(fill([4, 6, 8, 10,12,14,18,20], '*', 1, 3)); // => [4, "*", "*", 10, 12, 14, 18, 20]
```

Comment: I didn't know that the native `fill` had `start` and `end` parameters. That's very useful.